# Can't see the SCM blame infomation in Sonar

Tags: svn, ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I've just installed SCM Activity plugin 1.8 in Sonar 4.5 following the installation procedure. Subversion is also available on the server where Sonar is installed as well. I am using ANT target to start the sonar analysis.

I want to extract the blame information from SVN and want to show in the SoanrQube i.e., whenever a new issue arises it automatically assign to the culprit.

However as soon as I start a jenkins 1.532 job to run Sonar metrics, I've got the following output console:

```
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:07.778 INFO  - Execute Findbugs 2.0.3 done: 947 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:07.779 INFO  - Sensor FindbugsSensor done: 948 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:07.779 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.426 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 647 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.427 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.428 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 1 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.428 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.431 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 3 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - Sensor FileHashSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - parsing /export/bld/monetbld/jenkins/workspace/MONET Sonar Build/monet-web/.sonar/org.codehaus.sonar_Monet_monet-repricing/build/surefire-reports
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 WARN  - Reports path not found: /export/bld/monetbld/jenkins/workspace/MONET Sonar Build/monet-web/.sonar/org.codehaus.sonar_Monet_monet-repricing/build/surefire-reports
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor done: 0 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - Sensor ScmActivitySensor...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.432 INFO  - Found SCM type: svn
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.433 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.467 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding UTF-8 done: 34 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.467 INFO  - Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 35 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.468 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped)...
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.468 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.469 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.482 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped) done: 14 ms
[sonar:sonar] 17:52:08.611 INFO  - Execute decorators...
```

It says that blame information is retreived from svn but still i am not able to see it on sonar. 
Line says report path not found. Does that effect it?

Comment: where can we set these properties ?  sonar.jazzrtc.username and sonar.jazzrtc.password

Answer (score 1):

Since SonarQube 4.5, you need to turn on SCM decoration on the Component Viewer to be able to see SCM information. See the [documentation on the SCM Tab](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Information+tab).

Comment: I have turn on the SCM decoration on component bar but still did not get it.

Answer (score 0):

Blame information are not displayed by default in SonarQube.
You have to click on the blue bar right on top of the SCM icon to toggle blame information. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Information+tab

Comment: I have clicked on blue bar on top of SCM icon but still i can't see it.

Comment: Anybody knows about it?
That blue bar above SCM tab is not working. Still not getting it.